# Jqgrid Error code: 200 when editing

Tags: jqgrid, edit

I have a jqgrid issue. Whenever I edit one row in a grid, it's working perfectly as it changes the values in the database, but in the edit window I get "parsererror Status: 'OK'. Error code: 200". After that, I need to recharge the page in order to see the changes, that have been made.
Here is the code:

```
          tableToGrid("#tabla",  
    {
        caption:'Lista de tramos',
        datatype:'json',
        mtype:'POST',
        loadonce:true,
        jsonReader:{repeatitems: false,  id:"0"},
        url:'json/TramosJQGrid.jsp',
        editurl:'json/operacionesTramos.jsp',        
        colNames:[
            'Codigo','AIC','Arqueta inicio','Latitud','Longitud','AFC','Arqueta fin','Latitud','Longitud','Comentario','Entidad' 
        ],

        colModel:[
            {name:'codigo',index:'codigo',hidden:true,editable:false,key:true,width:'100'},      
            {name:'elemReg1',index:'elemReg1',hidden:true,editable:false,editrules:{required:true}},
            {name:'elemReg1Nombre',index:'elemReg1Nombre',editable:false,editrules:{required:true}},
            {name:'elemReg1Lat',index:'elemReg1',editable:false,editrules:{required:true}},
            {name:'elemReg1Lon',index:'elemReg1',editable:false,editrules:{required:true}},
            {name:'elemReg2',index:'elemReg2',hidden:true,editable:false,editrules:{required:true}},
            {name:'elemReg2Nombre',index:'elemReg2Nombre',editable:false,editrules:{required:true}},
            {name:'elemReg2Lat',index:'elemReg2',editable:false,editrules:{required:true}},
            {name:'elemReg2Lon',index:'elemReg2',editable:false,editrules:{required:true}},
            {name:'comentario',index:'comentario',editable:true},
            {name:'entidad',index:'entidad',stype:'select',searchoptions:{dataUrl:'json/entidades.jsp',searchhidden:true},editable:true,edittype:'select',editoptions:{dataUrl:'json/entidades.jsp'}}

        ],

        sortable:true,        
        height:'auto',
        pager:jQuery('#navegacion'),
        viewrecords:true,
        rowNum:25,
        rowList:[10,15,20,25,50,75,100,150,200],           
        multiselect:'true',

    ondblClickRow:sacaMapaTramoUnico


});


//Definición de barra de navegación
    jQuery("#tabla").navGrid('#navegacion',
            {
                    searchtext:'Buscar',
                    refresh:true,
                    view:true,
                    add:false,
                    viewtitle:'Ver registro',
                    alertcap:'ATENCION',
                    alerttext:'No puede realizarse la operacion porque no ha seleccionado ninguna fila.'
            },
            {}, //edición
            {}, //nuevo
            {}, //borrado
            {closeAfterSearch:true, modal:true}, //buscar
            {} //ver registro
    );

        //Botón de eliminar selección
    jQuery("#tabla").navButtonAdd('#navegacion',
        {
            caption: "Eliminar selec.", buttonicon: "", position:"first",cursor:"pointer", title: "Eliminar selección",
            onClickButton: function() {                       
                $("#tabla").jqGrid('resetSelection');
            }
        });

                //Botón de seleccionar todo
jQuery("#tabla").navButtonAdd('#navegacion',
        {
            caption: "Selec. todos", buttonicon: "", position:"first",cursor:"pointer", title: "Seleccionar todo",
            onClickButton: function() {                       
                $("#tabla").jqGrid('resetSelection');
                var ids = $("#tabla").getDataIDs();
                for (var i=0, il=ids.length; i < il; i++) {
                    $("#tabla").jqGrid('setSelection',ids[i], true);
                }
            }
    });

                        //Botón de ver en mapa
jQuery("#tabla").navButtonAdd('#navegacion',
        {
            caption: "Ver en mapa", buttonicon: "ui-icon-image", position:"first",cursor:"pointer", title: "Ver en mapa",
            onClickButton: sacaMapaTramos
    });



$("#tabla").sortGrid('fecha');
```

Answer (score 0):

get response from your  file define in edit Url:

```
int i=0;
    i=statement.executeUpdate("update jqgrid set name='"+name+"',contact='"+contact+"' where id='"+id+"'");
    if(i==0)
        {
        System.out.println("insertion failled");
        obj.put("res","insertion failled");
        }else
        {
        System.out.println("insertion succeed"+name+" "+contact);
        obj.put("res","insertion succeed");
        }
```

Vaibhav soni